# Mongodb combine aggregate queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following collections in MongoDB

Profile Collection

```
> db.Profile.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ec62ccb8897af3841a46d46"), "u" : "Test User", "is_del": false }
```

Store Collection

```
> db.Store.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eaa939aa709c30ff4703ffd"), "id" : "5ec62ccb8897af3841a46d46",  "a" : { "ci": "Test City", "st": "Test State" }, "ip" : false }, "op" : [ ], "b" : [ "normal" ], "is_del": false}
```

Item Collection

```
> db.Item.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea98a25f1246b53a46b9e10"), "sid" : "5eaa939aa709c30ff4703ffd", "n" : "sample", "is_del": false}
```

Relation among these collections are defined as follows:

1. `Profile -> Store`: It is `1:n` relation. `id` field in `Store` relates with `_id` field in `Profile`.
2. `Store` -> `Item`: It is also `1:n` relation. `sid` field in `Item` relates with `_id` field in `Store`.

Now, I need to write a query to find the all the store of profiles alongwith their count of `Item` for each store. Document with `is_del` as `true` must be excluded.

I am trying it following way:

1. Query 1 to find the count of item for each store.
2. Query 2 to find the store for each profile.

Then in the application logic use both the result to produce the combined output.

I have query 1 as follows:

```
db.Item.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$sid", count:{$sum:1}}})
```

Query 2 is as follows:

```
db.Profile.aggregate([{ "$addFields": { "pid": { "$toString": "$_id" }}},   { "$lookup": {"from": "Store","localField": "pid","foreignField": "id",  "as": "stores"}}])
```

In the query, `is_del` is also missing. Is there any simpler way to perform all these in a single query? If so, what will be scalability impact?

Comment: The structure of your documents in Store collection is a bit strange, is there supposed to be a closing curly bracket after `"ip": false` ?

Comment: Why don't you post some sample data of all collections?

Comment: @thammada.ts Thanks for pointing out. I think Ashh corrected this.

Comment: @varman: Sample data is there. If you need more info, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use uncorrelated sub-queries, available from MongoDB v3.6

```
db.Profile.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { is_del: false }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Store",
      as: "stores",
      let: {
        pid: { $toString: "$_id" }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            is_del: false,
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$pid", "$id"] }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "Item",
            as: "items",
            let: {
              sid: { $toString: "$_id" }
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  is_del: false,
                  $expr: { $eq: ["$$sid", "$sid"] }
                }
              },
              {
                $count: "count"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$items"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sPEXKdtN0-Y)

To improve performance, I suggest you store the reference ids as `ObjectId` so you don't have to convert them in each step.