# MongoDB paginate in aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following collections in MongoDB

Profile Collection

```
> db.Profile.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ec62ccb8897af3841a46d46"), "u" : "Test User", "is_del": false }
```

Store Collection

```
> db.Store.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eaa939aa709c30ff4703ffd"), "id" : "5ec62ccb8897af3841a46d46",  "a" : { "ci": "Test City", "st": "Test State" }, "ip" : false }, "op" : [ ], "b" : [ "normal" ], "is_del": false}
```

Item Collection

```
> db.Item.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea98a25f1246b53a46b9e10"), "sid" : "5eaa939aa709c30ff4703ffd", "n" : "sample", "is_del": false}
```

Relation among these collections are defined as follows:

1. `Profile -> Store`: It is `1:n` relation. `id` field in `Store` relates with `_id` field in `Profile`.
2. `Store` -> `Item`: It is also `1:n` relation. `sid` field in `Item` relates with `_id` field in `Store`.

I have a query to find the all the store of profiles alongwith their count of `Item` for each store. Query is given as below (I got it from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63109292/1629262))

```
db.Profile.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { is_del: false }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Store",
      as: "stores",
      let: {
        pid: { $toString: "$_id" }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            is_del: false,
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$pid", "$id"] }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "Item",
            as: "items",
            let: {
              sid: { $toString: "$_id" }
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  is_del: false,
                  $expr: { $eq: ["$$sid", "$sid"] }
                }
              },
              {
                $count: "count"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$items"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Now, I need to paginate over the result. How can I paginate in the aggregate result? What is a scalable approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to add

```
{
    $limit: limit
}, {
    $skip: skip
}
```

After

```
{
    $unwind: "$items"
}
```

Basically, on a query level you want to LIMIT your query to, let's say 10 elements, but SKIP first 5 (you load records for 2nd page, 5 records per page). I believe you'd have to calculate `limit` and `skip` each time.